# Localisation in WPF not working with single executable

Tags: wpf, internationalization, exe, wpflocalizationextension

I have an WPF application that supports 3 languages which works perfectly in debug. But when published to a single executable it doesn't work.

I think the problem is that he can't find my resource files in a single executable.

Package used to translate: [WPFLocalizeExtension](https://github.com/XAMLMarkupExtensions/WPFLocalizeExtension)

The properties of my resource files:

[image]

It works when published to a folder in debug, so fairly sure it's related to the fact that the single executable can't find the resource files.

I tried changing the properties to the screenshot above but didn't work.

If there is any more information needed don't hesitate to ask!

Anybody experienced this is in the past? how did you solve it?